# Ruby SOAP::RPC::Driver seeing the generated soap request

Tags: ruby, soap, rpc

I'm using ruby's WSDLFactory to create an rpc driver to access the paypoint soap service and i need to see what xml request is being generated is there a way to do this code or should i try and use something like ethereal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wiredump_dev=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9/libdoc/soap/rdoc/classes/SOAP/RPC/Driver.html#M001292) and/or [`wiredump_file_base=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9/libdoc/soap/rdoc/classes/SOAP/RPC/Driver.html#M001296).

For example,
`wiredump_dev = STDOUT` will output the generated request to the console and `wiredump_file_base = "/tmp/soap_log_"` will append the generated request to a file named soap_log_**method_name_called**.log